# How to emit TS declarations for legacy CommonJS dependencies with correct "module"

Tags: typescript, tsc, type-declaration

I'm trying to generate type declarations for old dependencies I use, which emit CJS modules and have no typings of their own. For example, the [aabb-3d](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aabb-3d) module (though this issue isn't specific to that module).

I'm generating the declaration with a command like:

```sh
tsc node_modules/aabb-3d/index.js 
    --allowJs 
    --declaration 
    --emitDeclarationOnly 
    --outFile types/aabb-3d/index.d.ts
```

This works, and the declaration gets generated, but the contents of the file look like:

```
declare module "index" {
    export = AABB;
    function AABB(pos: any, vec: any): AABB;
    //...
```

When I then try to edit code, my editor doesn't pick up the typings because it expects the declaration to be declaring the module `aabb-3d`, not `index`.

If I manually change the generated `d.ts` file, my editor works and code hints work correctly for the legacy module. How can I get `tsc` to generate working declaration files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked TypeScript's own code, and there's no evident way to change how the `declare module` line is generated. Fortunately, you can just prevent it from being generated at all. You're getting an ambient external module declaration (`declare module`) because you're using `--outFile` instead of `--outDir`. Here's how to generate the same `types/aabb-3d/index.ts` file as an ES-style module declaration without `declare module`:

```sh
tsc node_modules/aabb-3d/index.js 
    --allowJs 
    --declaration 
    --emitDeclarationOnly 
    --outDir types/aabb-3d
```

In order for TypeScript to find the ES-style module declarations in the `types` tree, you'll need the following in your project's `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
    ...
    "compilerOptions": {
        ...
        "typeRoots": [
            "./types",
            "./node_modules/@types"
        ],
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "paths": {
            "*": [
                "./types/*",
                "*"
            ]
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Then you can `import aabb3d from 'aabb-3d'` in your code with the typing in place, such as it is when tsc auto-generates it.

In case a package's `"main"` file is not named `index.js` and thus the generated declarations are not named `index.d.ts`, you will need to put a `package.json` file in the `types/$package` directory to point the compiler to the right file. For example, if the main file were `main.js`, making the declarations file `main.d.ts`, the `package.json` would be:

```json
{
    "types": "main.d.ts"
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks! I see what you mean, and it works for that dependency. However it seems to only work if the target library names its main file `index.js`. If I try it on, say, `node_modules/foo/main.js` then `tsc` builds `types/foo/main.d.ts`, and VScode doesn't find the typings unless I rename the file to `index.d.ts`. 

Is this unavoidable? I notice that I could also manually add a `paths` entry to tsconfig that maps `foo` to `./types/foo/whatever.d.ts`, and that seems to work, but it would be nice not to need to do this for every dependency.

Comment: @fenomas I amended my answer to cover this case. Basically, the `types` directory is treated just like `node_modules/@types` would be, so each of its subdirectories is more or less a package of its own. A `package.json` file can be used to point in the right direction. Probably no more ideal than having to add `paths` entries, but at least it pairs more directly with the files in question.

Comment: I see what you mean. Sort of non-ideal both ways... now that I check closely I see that for some of my legacy modules your approach emits quite different types than what I was getting with `outFile`, but this is presumably a side effect of the module being structured weirdly. Anyway I understand the options now, thanks much!